# Hybris custom layout page

Tags: layout, content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud

My problem is the following:

I have a requirement to create a new website with custom layout, for example;

[image]

What I do is copy a homepage template and then re-write the Velocity HTML template by making it look the same as the above mentioned scheme. However, when i add Logo and then banner, the positions are not correct, the logo appears in the top left corner, but the banner does not appear in the right at all. When I add minicart component it appears above the logo and the banner, and not below the logo as the requirement states. Everything is messed up, even though the velocity template looks fine. Maybe I'm missing something...can someone with more experience help me and give me an advice? Do I need to create a new accelerator or something? Or I can just copy an existing page templates, re-write the velocity HTML template and use it  (as I'm currently doing)?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, Velocity File is just a convenience for cms manager to looks proper each and every component in the correct slot. but even if you change cms position in your html landing page, you will get different Style. You have to manage your layout in landing page also. Recheck whethere your position name is same as you are defining in your landing page.

Comment: Yes, the position names are the same as the defined in the landing page.

Answer (score 0):

If this is hybris then the layout of the Storefront is nothing to do with Velocity at all.